# How to create a list containing names of functions?

Tags: python, list, function

I am completely new to python and programming but I am trying to learn it using more practical approach.

What I am trying to do is an exercise for converting different units, e.g. pounds -> kilograms, foot -> meter etc.

I have defined all the functions for different unit pairs:

```
def kg_to_g(value):     
    return round(value*1000.0,2)
def g_to_kg(value):     
    return round(value/1000.0,2)
def inch_to_cm(value):  
    return round(value*2.54,2)
def cm_to_inch(value):  
    return round(value/2.54,2)
def ft_to_cm(value):    
    return round(value*30.48,2)
```

etc.

and created a list with names of these functions:

```
unit_list = ['kg_to_g','g_to_kg','inch_to_cm','cm_to_inch',
         'ft_to_cm','cm_to_ft','yard_to_m','m_to_yard',
         'mile_to_km','km_to_mile','oz_to_g','g_to_oz',
         'pound_to_kg','kg_to_pound','stone_to_kg','kg_to_stone',
         'pint_to_l','l_to_pint','quart_to_l','l_to_quart',
         'gal_to_l','l_to_gal','bar_to_l','l_to_bar']
```

The program should randomly choose a unit pair(e.g. kg->pounds) and value (e.g. 134.23), and the user will be asked to convert those values.

```
random_unit = random.choice(unit_list)
lower = 0.1001
upper = 2000.1001
range_width = upper - lower
ranval = round(random.random() * range_width + lower, 2)
```

When user enters answer, the program should compare answer with the calculations defined by function and tell user if it is a correct answer or wrong answer:

```
def input_handler(answer):
    if answer == random_unit(ranval):
        label2.set_text("Correct!")
    else:
        label2.set_text("Wrong!")
```

Unfortunately, that way program doesn't work, and codesculptor(codesculptor.org) returns with an error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Could someone please explain to me what is wrong with the code and suggest something to solve the problem.

Comment: Add `random_unit = globals()[random_unit]` after `random_unit = random.choice(unit_list)`.

Comment: `random_unit = random.choice(unit_list)`: this line will assign a random item of `unit_list` (which is a list of `str`) to `random_unit`. You then call `random_unit(ranval)`, so you're using an `str` like a function (a callable is another name for function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've enclosed the function names (in the list) in quotes, they have become strings.

Change your list to:

```
unit_list = [kg_to_g, g_to_kg, inch_to_cm, cm_to_inch,
         ft_to_cm, cm_to_ft, yard_to_m, m_to_yard,
         mile_to_km, km_to_mile, oz_to_g, g_to_oz,
         pound_to_kg, kg_to_pound, stone_to_kg, kg_to_stone,
         pint_to_l, l_to_pint, quart_to_l, l_to_quart,
         gal_to_l, l_to_gal, bar_to_l, l_to_bar]
```

And now it is a list of functions, which can be called like this: `unit_list[0](34)`, for example.

So now `random_unit(ranval)` should not throw an exception.

Note also that comparing floats (`if answer == random_unit(ranval)`) will most likely cause you problems. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-brokenfor) for some detailed explanations of why this is.

As you are rounding you may get away with it, but it's good to be aware of this and understand that you need to deal with it in your code.

Comment: `getattr` won't be required here?

Comment: @PEJK No, not if the functions are hard-coded in the list, like this. If you have the name of a function in a variable and want to call it, then yes, `getattr()` is your friend, but it is not necessary here. When the list is defined, the elements are references to the functions themselves.

Comment: This solution worked for me! Thank you! My fault was that I defined my unit pair functions AFTER I created a list of unit pairs - that led to an error stating that function was not defined.

Comment: But now given an element from that list (`unit_list[2]` for example), how do you find out its name so you know what units it is converting?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are asking about.  You should be able to store the functions in a list like this

```
unit_list = [kg_to_g, g_to_kg, inch_to_cm, cm_to_inch, ft_to_cm]
```

You can then call each item in the list and give it a parameter and it should execute the function for example like this:

```
unit_list[0](value)
```